# EditorForModel shows nothing on the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The model is

```
public class AdminTicket
{
    public int Id;

    public string Title;

    public string Description;

    public DateTime CreationDate;
}
```

The action is

```
 public ViewResult EditTicket(int id)
    {
        return View(_ticketRepository.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id));
    }
```

(I checked, an action give to a view the right model)
The view is

```
@model TicketSystemMVC5.Models.AdminTicket
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditTicket", "Admin")) 
{ 
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Title)
@Html.EditorForModel()
<input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
@Html.ActionLink("Вернуться к списку", "Index") 
}
```

The result is a form with Title-editor, a button and a link. Where are all the editor fields?

Comment: Are you sure `FirstOrDefault` does not return `null` in your query?

Comment: Are you sure your action is actually returning a model? `FirstOrDefault` can return `null` if it can't find a ticket for the id you're passing, in which case you need to return a new, empty model.

Comment: Action is really returning a model. EditorFor 1 field works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditorForModel` doesn't like fields, it only renders properties - you can use the "auto-properties" quite happily:

```
public class AdminTicket {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Title { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }

  public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then your input fields will magically appear.

This is [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430917.aspx) (emphasis added):

> Returns an HTML input element for each *property* in the model.

To test, this I created the following class:

```
public class AdminTicket {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Title;

  public string Description;

  public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

And `EditorForModel` resulted in:

[image: Missing Fields from EditorForModel]